# iOS AudioServicesPlayAlertSound on silent with headphones

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to use `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound()` to play a chime when the device is on silent, but connected to headphones? In my app I have an AVPlayer, and when I use `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound` it does a nice job of turning down the AVPlayer audio, playing the chime, and then continuing. But, it doesn't do this if the user is on silent/vibrate.

Is there a way to play the chime in the same manner through the headphones, or is there an easy alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure that there is an easy way to do this. But if you really need to solve this problem you should look to AudioUnit framework. It's no easy, but it's very low level and you will able to play sound in any way.